# Multipart upload inside PHPUnit test

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm, multipartform-data, multipart

I am trying to make a multipart post request inside PhpStorm. I want to upload a file. I have inside function:

```
$this->post($uri, "[]", $this->setMyHeaders());
```

But where to put file in.

Comment: You don't actually upload a file, you mock it.

Comment: I don't understand, can you please describe more ?